# How do I inject raw CloudFormation into AWS SAM templayte.yml ? Want to setup SQS FIFO as event source for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, aws-sam

AWS SAM currently does not support SQS FIFO queues as event store for lambda. 
FIFO queues as event stores are fairly new to AWS however with CloudFormation I should be able to achieve the desired outcome. So how do I inject raw CloudFormation into the SAM template.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`AWS::Serverless` transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html) leaves all CloudFormation resource types outside of the `AWS::Serverless` namespace unmodified:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  FifoQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: true
```